# html-mode: publish to browser and jump to cursor location

Tags: html

In `html-mode`, how can a user publish an html page to browser (`browse-url-of-buffer`), and also jump to the approximate location in the webpage as the cursor in the corresponding Emacs buffer.

Answer (score 5):

One way is using an elisp function and a temporary anchor in the html:

- Surround the line where cursor is with an anchor `<a name='CursorPosition'>`
- Use `browse-url-firefox` (or preferred browser) to include that anchor (`#CursorPosition`)

Working example:

```
(defun browse-url-of-buffer-with-cursor-position ()
  """Browse url of buffer, jumping to location of cursor"""
  (interactive)
  (let* ((p1 (point-at-bol))
         (p2 (point-at-eol))
         (old-buffer (current-buffer))
         (old-line (thing-at-point 'line t))
         (replacement-line (concat  "<a name=\"CursorPosition\">" old-line "</a>")))
    (get-buffer-create "*temp-browse*")
    (with-current-buffer "*temp-browse*"
      (erase-buffer)
      (insert-buffer-substring old-buffer)
      (replace-string old-line replacement-line nil (point-min) (point-max))

      ;; directly from browse-url-of-buffer:
      (let ((file-name
               ;; Ignore real name if restricted
               (and (not (buffer-narrowed-p))
                      (or buffer-file-name
                          (and (boundp 'dired-directory) dired-directory)))))
        (when (or (not file-name)
                  ;; This can happen when we're looking at a file from a
                  ;; zip file buffer, for instance.
                  (not (file-exists-p file-name)))
            (unless browse-url-temp-file-name
              (setq browse-url-temp-file-name
                      (convert-standard-filename
                       (make-temp-file
                        (expand-file-name "burl" browse-url-temp-dir)
                        nil ".html"))))
            (setq file-name browse-url-temp-file-name)
            (write-region (point-min) (point-max) file-name nil 'no-message))

        ;; customized to add cursor position anchor
        (setq new-url (concat (browse-url-file-url file-name) "#CursorPosition"))
        (browse-url-firefox new-url)))))
```

Note this uses a temporary buffer and will not modify the original buffer/html.